# Why is the scrollHeight of textarea sometimes 0?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want to reset the height of textarea according to the height of the content inside it. My problem is that the `scrollHeight` sometimes returns `0`. The `textareas` are being made in `ajax` success request.

```
$('.offer-simple').click(function(){ // .offer-simple is a bootstrap tab link
    $("#offer_table textarea").each(function () {
        let height = $(this).prop('scrollHeight') + 3;
        console.log(height);//0
        $(this).css('height',height + 'px');
    });
});
```

The other thing which is very strange is that I am using the bootstrap tabs and when I reload the page while the current bootstrap tab is opened then it gives the perfect height but whenever the other bootstrap tab is opened while reloading the page and then I click back to the `tab` where actually the textareas are placed then it doesn't give the perfect `scrollHeight` in that case.
[image]

Comment: You question contains a contradiction. First you say: "My problem is that the `scrollHeight` always returns `0`.", but later on you say: "... then it gives the perfect height ...". Which is it?

Comment: So the only time the height of the textareas is set correctly is when the page loads for the first time _without_ running your js snippet?

Comment: @yiffyiffyiff No. When the tab is opened where the textareas are placed. Script runs each time because all the content is being created in ajax success

Comment: This might be a "feature" of the browser you are using. It simply doesn't bother to compute the `scrollHeight` of an element that's not shown. What you could try, just before you get the `scrollHeight`, is to change some property of the text area that would make the browser recompute the `scrollHeight`. A change of font height or padding for instance.